# To recover harddrive of partial formatting to NTFS from FAT

Tags: hard-disk, ntfs

I have a partial formatting of a new disk (2TB of Buffalo) which I was going to format into NTFS from FAT (most probably fileformat of new disks).
However, I removed the cable by accident. 
No important files there, since new disk. 
I can just see the disk connection /dev/disk/ but not in system GUI.

I know this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73553/16920).
I run

```
ls -la /dev/disk/by-id/usb-BUFFALO_HD-PNFU3_0000000300001199-0\:0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jul 10 22:59 /dev/disk/by-id/usb-BUFFALO_HD-PNFU3_0000000300001199-0:0 -> ../../sdb
```

and

```
testdisk /debug /dev/disk/by-id/usb-BUFFALO_HD-PNFU3_0000000300001199-0\:0
```

and

```
photorec /debug /dev/sdb
```

and getting nothing relevant as result.

### Running Jodka's commands

`/dev/sdb` is correct location, since the Buffalo disk is 2TB:

```
lsblk /dev/sdb
NAME MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb    8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk
```

and running the `wipefs` command but getting that the options not existing:

```
$ wipefs -fv /dev/sdb 
wipefs: invalid option -- 'v'

Usage:
 wipefs [options] <device>

Options:
 -a, --all           wipe all magic strings (BE CAREFUL!)
 -b, --backup        create a signature backup in $HOME
 -f, --force         force erasure
 -h, --help          show this help text
 -n, --no-act        do everything except the actual write() call
 -o, --offset <num>  offset to erase, in bytes
 -p, --parsable      print out in parsable instead of printable format
 -q, --quiet         suppress output messages
 -t, --types <list>  limit the set of filesystem, RAIDs or partition tables
 -V, --version       output version information and exit
```

The version is `wipefs from util-linux 2.25.2`.

Running the last two commands

```
$ sudo mkfs.ntfs -f /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb is entire device, not just one partition.
Refusing to make a filesystem here!
$ sudo mkfs.ntfs -f /dev/sdb1
Failed to access '/dev/sdb1': No such file or directory
The device doesn't exist; did you specify it correctly?
```

I still see nothing in `ls /media/masi/` so the disk has not been usable.

### Running Jodka's additions

I do not see the disk in */media/masi/* after these commands:

```
$ sudo wipefs -fa /dev/sdb
$ ls /media/masi/

$sudo wipefs -fa /dev/sdb1
wipefs: error: /dev/sdb1: probing initialization failed: No such file or directory
```

Why do you want to run the last command into /dev/sdb1? 
I do not have such a disc. The command `ls /dev/sd*` gives just `/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5  /dev/sdb`.

Running still the last commands again

```
sudo gdisk /dev/sdb 
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.10

Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries.

Command (? for help): x

Expert command (? for help): z
About to wipe out GPT on /dev/sdb. Proceed? (Y/N): Y
GPT data structures destroyed! You may now partition the disk using fdisk or
other utilities.
Blank out MBR? (Y/N): Y
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4M count=10
10+0 records in
10+0 records out
41943040 bytes (42 MB) copied, 1.62512 s, 25.8 MB/s
$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdb 
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.10

Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries.

Command (? for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1): 
First sector (34-3907029134, default = 2048) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 
Last sector (2048-3907029134, default = 3907029134) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 
Current type is 'Linux filesystem'
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300): 
Changed type of partition to 'Linux filesystem'

Command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): Y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/sdb.
The operation has completed successfully.
$ ls /media/masi/
$ mkfs.ntfs -f /dev/sdb
sdb   sdb1  
$ sudo mkfs.ntfs -f /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb is entire device, not just one partition.
Refusing to make a filesystem here!
$ sudo mkfs.ntfs -f /dev/sdb1
Cluster size has been automatically set to 4096 bytes.
Creating NTFS volume structures.
mkntfs completed successfully. Have a nice day.
$ ls /media/masi/
```

I finally get the disc working by running lastly

```
$sync
// disconnect the cable and put back
$ls /media/masi/
7935137E18608463
```

How can you recover partial formatted disk of NTFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand, there are no files you want to keep.

To be sure, you are working on the right harddisk run `lsblk` to list all connected drives.

I would use wipefs on it first:

`wipefs -a /dev/sdb1` and `wipefs -a /dev/sdb`

Then start `gdisk /dev/sdb` and press `x` and then `z` to wipe the mbr and gpt.

Maybe zero the first megabytes:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4M count=10
```

Then start fdisk (for old mbr) or gdisk (for modern gpt), depending of size and create new partition(s).

`gdisk /dev/sdb` -> `n` -> ENTER -> ENTER -> ENTER -> `0700` for type 0x0700 (Microsoft basic data) -> `w` to write to disk

or

`fdisk /dev/sdb` -> `n` -> `p` -> `1` -> ENTER -> ENTER; `t`-> `7` for type 0700 Microsoft basic data -> `w` to write to disk

and then format it with

```
mkfs.ntfs -f /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: I added the ouptus of your two first commands. The flags `fv` are not existing in my `wipefs`. I have `wipefs from util-linux 2.25.2`. What is your wipefs?

Comment: My mistake. It's `wipefs -a /dev/sdb1` and `wipefs -a /dev/sdb`. The `-f`is mandatory in this case.

Comment: I added the outputs of the commands in the new flow. Still not seeing the disc by `ls /volumes/masi/`.

Comment: The command about /dev/sdb1 was more of a general thing. After gdisk, you have created a partition. Then you should have the device `/dev/sdb1` (first partition on drive sdb). Then format it with mkfs.ntfs -f /dev/sdb1, so you have a formatted partition. At this point you should be fine with your drive. You can run a `sync` and remove and reattach the cable and see what happens.

Comment: Works! Thank you! I run `sync`; reattach cable and see the disk as `ls /media/masi/ 7935137E18608463`.

Answer (score 1):

You can zero-fill the drive with

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M`

Make sure `/dev/sdb` is actually the correct device name!

Comment: Can you estimate how long this will take? I have waited now 2 hours with the command.

Comment: Long, but it's only necessary when you want to be sure the old data is not findable. It doesn't really make sense, when this is a new drive.

Comment: `kill -USR1 <pid>` will show the current progress of `dd`.

Comment: I let my machine do this 24h but never finished.